# Understanding reading txt files in c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to understand reading different txt file formats in c++

I am currently trying to read a file formatted like this,

```
val1 val2 val3
val1 val2 val3
val1 val2 val3
```

When I read the file in and then `cout` its contents I only get the first line then a random `0 0` at the end.

I want to save each value into its own variable in a struct.

I am doing this like this,

```
struct Input{
    std::string group;
    float total_pay;
    unsigned int quantity;

    Input(std::string const& groupIn, float const& total_payIn, unsigned int const& quantityIn):
    group(groupIn),
    total_pay(total_payIn),
    quantity(quantityIn)
    {}
};

int main(){

    std::ifstream infile("input.txt");
    std::vector<Input> data;

    std::string group;
    std::string total_pay;
    std::string quantity;

    std::getline(infile,group);
    std::getline(infile,total_pay);
    std::getline(infile,quantity);

    while(infile) {
        data.push_back(Input(group,atof(total_pay.c_str()),atoi(quantity.c_str())));

        std::getline(infile,group);
        std::getline(infile,total_pay);
        std::getline(infile,quantity);
    }


    //output
    for(Input values : data) {
        std::cout << values.group << " " << values.total_pay << " " << values.quantity << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What is the proper way to read this file in the the format I have specified? Do I need to specify to go to the next line after the third value?

Or should this be taking each value and putting them in to the right variable?

```
std::getline(infile,group);
std::getline(infile,total_pay);
std::getline(infile,quantity);
```

Comment: Hint: `std::getline` reads a whole line.

Comment: what is the separator between fields? is each field may contain a white space?

Comment: yes there is a white space between each value. How do I read this in one value at a time? Ideally if I had 20 values and I wanted to read them in alternating what variable i store them in. so val1 = group val2 = total_pay val3 = quantity then starts over val4 = group and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input processing has a number of issues. Your prevalent usage of `std::getline` in places where it is not needed isn't helping.

In short, per-line validation of input is *generally* done with a model similar to the following. Note that this requires the class provide a default constructor. We use an input-string-stream to process a *single* item from each line of input from the input file. If it was **certain** there was at-most one per line, we could forego the per-line processing, but it is a potential place for errors, so better safe than sorry. The mantra presented here is commonly used for per-line input validation when reading a stream of objects from a formatted input file, one item per line.

The following code defines the structure as you have it with a few extra pieces, including providing both an input and output stream insertion operator. The result makes the code in `main()` *much* more manageable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

struct Input
{
    // friends not needed if the members are public, but provided here
    //  in case you ever do make them protected or private (which you should)
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& inp, Input& item);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outp, Input const& item);

    std::string group;
    float total_pay;
    unsigned int quantity;

    // default constructor. sets up zero-elements
    Input() : total_pay(), quantity()
    {
    }

    Input(std::string groupIn, float total_payIn, unsigned int quantityIn)
        : group(std::move(groupIn))
        , total_pay(total_payIn)
        , quantity(quantityIn)
    {
    }

    // you really should be using these for accessors
    std::string const& getGroup() const { return group; }
    float getTotalPay() const { return total_pay; }
    unsigned int getQuantity() const { return quantity; }
};

// global free function for extracting an Input item from an input stream
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& inp, Input& item)
{
    return (inp >> item.group >> item.total_pay >> item.quantity);
}

// global operator for inserting to a stream
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outp, Input const& item)
{
    outp << item.getGroup() << ' '
         << item.getTotalPay() << ' '
         << item.getQuantity();
    return outp;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("input.txt");
    if (!infile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open input file" << '\n';
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // one line per item enforced.
    std::vector<Input> data;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        Input inp;
        if (iss >> inp) // calls our extaction operator >>
            data.emplace_back(inp);
        else
            std::cerr << "Invalid input line: " << line << '\n';
    }

    // dump all of them to stdout. calls our insertion operator <<
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<Input>(std::cout,"\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Provided the input is properly formatted, values like this:

```
group total quantity
group total quantity
```

will parse successfully. Conversely, if this happens:

```
group total quantity
group quantity
group total quantity
total quantity
```

the extractions of the second and fourth items will fail, and appropriate warning will be issued on `std::cerr`. This is the reason for using the `std::istringstream` intermediate stream object wrapping extraction of a single line per item.

Best of luck, and I hope it helps you out.

Comment: Wow... Thank you so so much. This is amazingly helpful. The only thing that doesnt make sense to me is this line, 
` data.emplace_back(inp)` which I get an error at saying error: no member named 'emplace_back' in
      'std::__1::vector<Input, std::__1::allocator<Input> >'
            data.emplace_back(inp);

Comment: @NDiaz its a C++11 thing. If you're toolchain is not C++11 compliant (and it appears it isn't), use `push_back` instead. If you're using `gcc` or `clang`, of a C++11-compliant variety, you can use the command line switch `-std=c++11` to enable those features, otherwise, just roll with push-back.

Comment: I am compliant. I just dont know why its giving me that error.

Comment: But yea your right push_back works with no errors. You are the best man. Thank you tons.

Comment: Glad you have something that works. Check your switches on your compiler cmd-line. If `-std=c++11` isn't there, put it there. That may be the missing special-sauce.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution

It is without error checks but with conversion to types

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line="v1 2.2 3";//lets say you read a line to this var...
    string group;
    float total_pay;
    unsigned int quantity;
    //we split the line to the 3 fields
    istringstream s(line);
    s>>group>>total_pay>>quantity;
    //print for test
    cout<<group<<endl<<total_pay<<endl<<quantity<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: im sorry I have never used sstream before. Are you saying do this without ifstream?

Comment: you read the whole line with `ifstream` to the line variable, as you did before. my answer come after you read the line. you can as well read it directly from the `ifstream`, but then lines means nothing.

Comment: I am sorry I am having trouble putting it all together. I will keep working on it and accept when I figure it out. If you wouldn't mind showing me in your answer it would be much appreciated.